# NoMethodError for auto complete with rails3 autocomplete gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error saying “autocomplete method doesn't exist” with rails3-autocomplete gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677904/error-saying-autocomplete-method-doesnt-exist-with-rails3-autocomplete-gem)

I am trying to implement auto complete using rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem.
I am getting an error saying

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `autocomplete' for #<ReleasesController:0xb76febec>):
  app/controllers/releases_controller.rb:41:in `new'
```

I installed the gem and I am using it in my controller as

Controller code:

```
def new
autocomplete :users, :name 
end
```

View file:

```
= autocomplete_field_tag 'tester_name', '', users_autocomplete_user_name_path, :size => 75
```

On giving bundle install I am able to see the gem:

```
[root@sanduxvm01 trunk]# bundle install
Using rake (0.9.2)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.10)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.5.0)
Using activemodel (3.0.10)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.4)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.30)
Using actionpack (3.0.10)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.2)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.2.19)
Using actionmailer (3.0.10)
Using arel (2.0.10)
Using activerecord (3.0.10)
Using activeresource (3.0.10)
Using bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
Using bundler (1.0.17)
Using cancan (1.6.7)
Using cocaine (0.2.0)
Using orm_adapter (0.0.5)
Using warden (1.0.6)
Using devise (1.4.2)
Using dynamic_form (1.1.4)
Using formtastic (1.2.4)
Using haml (3.1.3)
Using json (1.6.1)
Using rdoc (3.11)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.10)
Using jquery-rails (1.0.16)
Using paperclip (2.4.4)
Using pg (0.11.0)
Using rails (3.0.10)
Using rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.5)
Using will_paginate (3.0.pre2)
```

Please let me know how to correct this error.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to put `autocomplete :users, :name` statement out of the new action, this way:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :users, :name 

  def new
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks alony, By giving it outside new I am gettign the following error "undefined local variable or method `autocomplete' for #<#<Class:0xb709ac24>:0xb7099a7c>"

Comment: that's weird as autocomplete method is defined inside the gem. Did you follow [this guide](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete)?

Comment: Yes alony,I followed the guide.Please let me know what should I add in my routes file in this case?