# error saying "autocomplete method doesn't exist" with rails3-autocomplete gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, rubygems

In my rails application I am trying to use rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem.
I included the following line in Gemfile.
'gem rails3-jquery-autocomplete' and gave bundle install and its listed in the gems.

My controller :

```
class ReleasesController < AuthorizedController
  # GET /releases
  # GET /releases.xml
    autocomplete :users, :name 

     def new 
    @release = Release.new
    @ic_ids = params[:ic_ids] ? params[:ic_ids] : []
     @testers = User.find_by_sql("select * from users where id in(select user_id from user_role_assignments where role_id in (select id from roles where name like 'Tester')) order by name").paginate(:page=>params[:page],:per_page=>30)   
   if params[:project_id]
      @release.project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @release }
          end
  end

  end
```

routes file:

```
get 'releases/autocomplete_users_name'
```

view file:

```
= autocomplete_field_tag 'tester_name', '', users_autocomplete_user_name_path, :size => 75
```

I am getting the error

```
undefined method `autocomplete' for #<ReleasesController:0xb731e2c0>
```

Please help me out here.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: The line with autocomplete should be: `autocomplete :user, :name`.

Comment: I think your view should contain at the end `... releases_autocomplete_user_name_path`. At the moment, the search for autocomplete starts in the wrong controller.

Comment: Yes I changed it is there any wrong in the routes file .I haved added  get 'releases/autocomplete_user_name' in my routes file. Also please let me know if I could check where the controller goes from this line = autocomplete_field_tag 'tester_name', '', users_autocomplete_user_name_path, :size => 75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run the generator ?
`rails generate autocomplete:install`

And within controller it should be

```
 Class SomeController
 autocomplete :user, :name 
   def yourmethods
   end
 end
```

Please look at the instructions here : 
https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Comment: Hi Gaurav,Yes I ran the generator. autocomplete is to be added to the controller only right? I guess its not to be added to the model

Comment: Hi Gaurav on giving it in the controller I am getting the following error:ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `autocomplete' for #<#<Class:0xb708002c>:0xb707efd8>):
    37:             -puts "testers=#{@testers}"
    38:             = form.label :tester_tokens, "Testers"
    39:             = form.text_field :tester_tokens
    40:             = autocomplete_field_tag 'tester_name', :data-autocomplete=>"autocomplete_users_name_path"
    41:             - @testers.each do |tester|
    42:               %tr
    43:                 %td=tester.name

Comment: yuo are giving in an action .. give outside it.

Comment: Yes I gave it globally in the controllers class

Comment: can you post your controller in the question properly

Comment: Hi Gaurav I have edited my question with the compelte controller code

Comment: look at @mliebelt comment.. it should be :user not :users

Comment: Hi Gaurav I changed that also.Please let me know if there are something to be added in my routes file? I have added  get 'releases/autocomplete_user_name'.